# How to retrieve two country date/time using single query?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to retrieve two different country date / time in single query? Whether I need to change any NLS parameters setting?
Sample query:

```
Select sysdate ind, sysdate us from dual;
```

O/p:

```
11/09/2015 3:05 PM  11/09/2015 05:35 AM
```

Comment: Wouldn't just knowing the time differences and adding / taking them away from the data object be sufficient?

Comment: Worth knowing maybe if you're not sure what timezone the server is in:  DBTIMEZONE, SESSIONTIMEZONE are useful objects

Comment: `DBTIMEZONE` is useless. It defines only the internal format for `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. It has no influence on any outputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
select systimestamp ind, systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern' us
from dual;
```

If you interested in date then;

```
select 
  cast(systimestamp as date) ind, 
  cast(systimestamp at time zone 'US/Eastern' as date) us
from dual;
```

[Reference for all Time Zones](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/applocaledata.htm#i637736)

You can use `FROM_TZ` and `TZ_OFFSET` to get the same result:

```
select sysdate ind, FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2015-09-11 15:50:42', TZ_OFFSET('US/Eastern')) us 
from dual;
```

If you want to know more about the time zones then:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tzname
FROM V$TIMEZONE_NAMES;
```

Please refer these links for [`FROM_TZ`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/from_tz.php) and [`TZ_OFFSET`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/tz_offset.php)

Comment: Some docs: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1007699

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it with the third `noptions` parameter of the [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2113.htm) function.

It also seems that you can use the [AT Timezone](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10749/ch4datet.htm#1007620) clause in your query

Here is an example given the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10749/ch4datet.htm#1007620) I gave (I am sorry I cannot test it for the moment):

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(TO_DATE('1999-12-01 11:00:00',
     'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP), 'America/New_York')
     AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' "West Coast Time"
FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP)` to get the current Coordinated Universal Time and then:

- India is 5½ Hours ahead of UTC;
- US EST is 4 hours behind UTC; and
- US PST is 7 hours behind UTC.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6199)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS TIME_UTC,
       TO_CHAR( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) + INTERVAL '5' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS TIME_INDIA,
       TO_CHAR( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '4' HOUR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS TIME_EST,
       TO_CHAR( SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '7' HOUR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3' ) AS TIME_PST
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6199/0)**:

```
|                TIME_UTC |              TIME_INDIA |                TIME_EST |                TIME_PST |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|
| 2015-09-11 10:04:22.482 | 2015-09-11 15:34:22.482 | 2015-09-11 06:04:22.482 | 2015-09-11 03:04:22.482 |
```

Comment: Not as good as the AT TIME ZONE method, which is sensitive to daylight savings time.

Comment: Quite bad idea to changes your query twice a year due to daylight saving.